# Stopping time Independent random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

I have a question.

- Let $X_{1},\ldots$ independent random variables with
  $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{i} = 2\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X_{i} = 0\right) = 1/2$ and let $Y= \prod_\limits{i = 1}^{n}X_{i}$ and we define
  $\tau = \min_{\, n\geq 1\,}\left(Y_{n} = 0\right)$.
- Calculate
  $\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{\tau -1}\right)$.
- My thoughts are ( sorry my bad English ): I can take $\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{\tau - 1}\right) =
  \mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{\tau - 1} \mid \tau\right)\right)$ then I developed the conditional expectation
  $\mathbb{E}\left(\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{\tau - 1} \mid \tau\right)\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{\tau - 1} \mid \tau = k\right)\mathbb{P}\left(\tau = k\right)$.
- But $\tau$ distribution is a $\mbox{geometric}\left(1/2\right)$ then 
  $\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{\tau - 1} \mid \tau = k\right)
  {1 \over 2^{k}}$.

  But here is where I have problems:

  First I guess they are not independent, I think $Y_{\tau - 1} \mid \tau$ is $2^{\tau - 1}$ but I'm stuck in this step.

Comment: You did not even take care of copying correctly your homework... so I guess that asking for some personal input would be seen as preposterous, right?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the exercise until I saw your comment. This is not my homework, it's just  I am not sure if I can take $\mathbb{E}(Y_{\tau-1}|\tau=k)=\mathbb{E}(Y_k)$ I think given $\tau$ $Y_{\tau-1}$ is not the same as $Y_k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ take only the values $\{0,2\}$, we have

$$\tau(\omega) = k \iff X_1(\omega)=X_2(\omega)=\ldots = X_{k-1}(\omega)=2, X_k(\omega)=0$$

for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies in particular that

$$Y_{\tau-1}(\omega) = Y_{k-1}(\omega) = \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} X_i(\omega) = 2^{k-1} \tag{1} $$

for any $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $\tau(\omega)=k$. On the other hand, we have by the monotone convergence theorem

$$\mathbb{E} \left( Y_{\tau-1} \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} Y_{k-1} 1_{\{\tau=k\}} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(Y_{k-1} 1_{\{\tau=k\}}).$$

Since we already know from $(1)$ that $Y_{k-1} 1_{\{\tau=k\}}= 2^{k-1} 1_{\{\tau=k\}}$ we conclude

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_{\tau-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{k-1} \mathbb{P}(\tau=k).$$

As $\mathbb{P}(\tau=k) = 2^{-k}$, this means that $\mathbb{E}(Y_{\tau-1}) = \infty$.